# Use Memcache for sessions only

Tags: 8, sessions, caching

I need to use memcache only for sessions.
We have PHP 7.1, php-memcached, and Drupal 8 with the Memcache module.

In session.php we put:

```
$settings['memcache']['servers'] = ['192.168.177.112:11211' => 'session_instance'];
$settings['memcache']['bins'] = [
    'session' => 'session_instance',
    'users' => 'session_instance',
];
$settings['memcache']['key_prefix'] = '';
$settings['memcache']['options'] = [
    Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION => Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT,
];
$settings['cache']['bins']['session'] = 'cache.backend.memcache';
$settings['cache']['bins']['users'] = 'cache.backend.memcache';
```

but the bins are wrong.
This code work only if we put:

```
$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.memcache'
```

or

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.memcache';
```

Any solution?
thanks